# Checking "encryption" and "decryption" of Caesar Cipher using strings in python

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

I was supposed to create strings in my python function to show that the encryption and decryption of my code was working properly. Below is my code.

```
def encrypt1():
    plain1 = input('Enter plain text message: ')
    cipher = ''

    for each in plain1:
        c = (ord(each)+3) % 126

        if c < 32: 
            c+=31

    cipher += chr(c)

    print ("Your encrypted message is:" + cipher)

encrypt1()
```

1.) I get the "Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces" error

2.) How should I input set, constant strings to get the wanted input check if my code works (for example, type in meet and get the correct input, etc)

Comment: you just have to indent this line `cipher += chr(c)`. Also, passing argument `plain1` to the function doesn't make sense since you overwrite it using `input()`. The python versions have nothing to do with this

Comment: ...do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mostly fine but there are a few issues that I've pointed out:

1. Your indenting is off. The line `cipher += chr(c)` should be indented to match the things in the for loop
2. The function encypt1() shouldn't take a parameter; you are setting plain1 in the method itself so you can declare it there
3. If you want to deal with just lowercase letters, you should be doing % 123 (value of 'z') and the if clause should check if `c < 97`. If you want to wrap around printable ascii what you're doing is fine.

This gives:

```
    def encrypt1():
        plain1 = input('Enter plain text message: ')
        cipher = ''
        for each in plain1:
            c = (ord(each)+3) % 126
            if c < 32: 
                c+=31
            cipher += chr(c)
        print ("Your encrypted message is:" + cipher)
```

Because you want to be able to test this on multiple strings, you would want to pass plain1 as a parameter to the function. But you also want the user to be able to input plain1 if a parameter isn't passed in to the function. For that I would suggest a default parameter. Look at the commented code below:

```
def encrypt1(plain1=""):        # if no argument is passed in, plain1 will be ""
    if not plain1:              # check if plain1 == "" and if so, read input from user
        plain1 = input('Enter plain text message: ')
    cipher = ''
    for each in plain1:
        c = (ord(each)+3) % 126
        if c < 32: 
            c+=31
        cipher += chr(c)
    return cipher               # rather than printing the string, return it instead
```

So to test this you could do:

```
test_strings = ['hello world', 'harambe', 'Name', 'InputString']

for phrase in test_strings:
    print ("Your encrypted message is:" + encrypt1(phrase))
```

Which gives the output:

```
Your encrypted message is:khoor#zruog
Your encrypted message is:kdudpeh
Your encrypted message is:Qdph
Your encrypted message is:LqsxwVwulqj
```

Comment: Your answer solves my error problems, but I still don't know how to input the strings :p

Comment: @YeoZheYong Ah I just saw the edit to your question. What do you mean input the strings? Do you want a way to test this on multiple strings somehow?

Comment: yes, sorry if I'm making a fool of myself, but our university module mostly involves html and javascript, with only a little bit of python, so inexperienced people like me end up rather confused when python/php questions come out

Comment: @YeoZheYong No worries, I've updated my answer. Let me know if I understood your question correctly and feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: you can also use `plain1 = plain1 or input('Enter plain text message: ')` since `or` shortcircuits. Also +1 for test string 'harambe'